# why the error is "Unrecognized flag '-FitObjData' in 'p2'" and fatal error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am getting this error "Unrecognized flag '-FitObjData' in 'p2'" and fatal error in visual stdio 2012 , why ?

Comment: Nobody knows. Please provide more details.

Comment: when the error is pressed I am not notified,the program suddenly error ? I can not give further details ...